# Which preposition to use when there are different conjuncts

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, conjunctions

I wrote:

> We particularly investigate the **attitude**, the degree of **familiarity** and the **need** of faculty **to** such a system.

I used three nouns each of which takes a different preposition:

- attitude **to/toward**
- familiarity **with**
- need **for**

Now which should I use between their conjunction and the *system*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**All of them**, because you have to use a conjunction and you can't use the wrong conjunction.  You can rephrase the sentence using "it" as the object of each phrase, as **"We particularly investigate the attitude of the faculty toward such a system, their degree of familiarity with it, and their need for it."**

You will also sometimes see constructions like **"We particularly investigate the faculty's attitude toward, degree of familiarity with, and need for such a system."**  (I think there is a name for this rhetorical device, but I cannot find it at the moment.)

Comment: +1 The device in your second paragraph is called "Right Node Raising" (RNR) and it's a legal barbarism which should be stamped out mercilessly.

Comment: @StoneyB - Thanks for the name!  I got a laugh out of "legal barbarism"...hey, some people hate the Oxford comma, some people hate singular they, some people hate right node raising...

Comment: The Oxford comma and singular *they* are spontaneous and vernacular; RNR is a wilful effort by people who should know better to prove that they're smarter than Great Mother English.